# smart use of PHP str_replace (or something similar)

Tags: php, arrays, variables, str-replace

There are a large numbers of PHP variables I use in my template files and some of them need to be accessible for editors who can only use HTML.  What I want to do exactly is have them identify the variable doing something like [ITEM_NAME_1] when typing/editing content, and PHP finds them because they are wrapped in brackets, and replaces them with the appropriate PHP variable (in that case, $ITEM_NAME_1)

The content of each page is in a variable "$page_content", so right now the only way I know how to accomplish is to manually write lines to replace what I need.

```
$page_content = str_replace("[ITEM_NAME_1]", "$ITEM_NAME_1", "$page_content"); 
print $page_content
```

The issue is there are hundreds of these "ITEM_NAME_X" variables and I don't want to have to create a massive repeat of "str_replace" lines manually for each ITEM_NAME_X.

What I want to accomplish is have PHP find anything inside $page_content that is wrapped in brackets [], take the name from inside the bracket and replace all of it with the variable of that bracketted name. So if it finds [ITEM_5], it replaces it with $ITEM_5. Is this at all possible? Let me know, thanks.

Comment: You could try a regular expression replacing `/\[([^]*)]/$\1/g` but this might be rather dangerous. I think you're better off doing what you are and *explicitly* replacing what you know and understand with variables. Otherwise a malicious user might write `[_POST]` or `[encrKey]` or something. (A dictionary of bracketed expression->variable names would work though, and you can loop through that instead.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [`preg_replace`](http://us.php.net/preg_replace) with the [`/e` modifier](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) a whirl. Combine that with [variable variable name syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to get the effect you want.

```
$page_content = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/e', '$$1', $page_content);
```

This uses a regex to match strings between square brackets. The strings are captured and are accessed with `$1` in the replacement string. The second `$` looks up the variable named with whatever's in `$1`.

If you want to do something more complicated with the replacement, you can invoke your own function from the replacement string. For example:

```
function substitute_tag($tag_name)
{
    $replacement_values = array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => '42', ...);
    return $replacement_values[$tag_name];
}

$page_content = preg_replace('/\[(.*?)\]/e', 'substitute_tag("$1")', $page_content);
```

Comment: Your first example literally does exactly what I needed. Perfect!! Is there anything I should know about this (performance or security-wise) that I should be aware of?

Comment: @ZackTaylor As lc commented, it's not secure. I highly recommend the second approach with a substitution array so user's can't substitute arbitrary variable names.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. In the $replacement_values = array line, what would 'foo' => 'bar' (and so on) be in my particular case? I'm still learning PHP and so I'm trying to figure out what exactly that line is doing/accomplishing for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ZackTaylor That's your mapping. `[foo]` is replaced with "bar", `[baz]` is replaced with "42", etc.

Answer (score 2):

this what i use:

```
public static function rewrite_curley($data,$message){

        if(is_array($data)){
            foreach($data as $key => $var){
                $find = '{'.$key.'}';
                $message = str_replace($find,$var,$message);
            }
            $message = preg_replace('/\{(.*)\}/','',$message); //strip any left over vars with out matches
        }
        return $message;

    }
```

obviously my variables are in {}, hence the function name

Comment: This function runs str_replace multiple times and so a regex. Isn't that faster to replace array_keys with their values in a single str_replace call?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use arrays as arguments for str_replace?

```
str_replace(array('string1', 'string2'), array('replacement1', 'replacement2'), $page_content);
```

This way you can avoid using regex.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this. But in case you have same token and replacement count, str_replace with arrays can be handy and smart.

Comment: A regex on a large string may be a big performance problem; whereas the array approach to str_replace may be far more efficient. There is also far less room for error.